# Send message from Postman to Microsoft Bot

Tags: botframework

I am trying to send a message to a bot I created and published to azure services so that the bot can then start messaging some of its users.

I am trying to make the requests on Postman first so that then I can build a controller for that interaction.

I am doing the following request:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body:
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: my_ms_app_id
client_secret: my_ms_app_secret
scope: https://api.botframework.com/.default
```

from this I get in the response the Bearer Authorization:

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXA..."
}
```

Then I proceed with the following request:

```
POST https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi....

{
    "bot": {
        "id": "i don't have this id so i pass some string",
        "name": "connector controller"
    },
    "isGroup": false,
    "members": [
        {
            "id": "28:...", //ID of the bot I want to send the message to
            "name": "Sp Bot"//Name of the bot I want to talk to
        },
       {
            "id": "i don't have this id so i pass some string",
            "name": "connector controller"
        }
    ],
    "topicName": "News Alert"
}
```

in response i get the conversation id which matches "id": "i don't have this id so i pass some string":
{
  "id": "i don't have this id so i pass some string"
}

Then I proceed with the following POST request:

```
POST. https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations/i don't have this id so i pass some string/activities
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0...
Content-Type:application/json
```

I get the following response:

```
400 Bad Request

{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "The conversationId 29... and bot .... doesn't match a known conversation"
  }
}
```

It looks like the problem occurs between the second and the 3 post method. It looks like that the https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations does not generate a conversation with the bot with Id I entered.

So when I make the final call to the bot: https://skype.botframework.com/v3/conversations/.../activities I always get the serviceError message.

Comment: You don't have the id of the bot? I assume your bot is registered in dev.botframework.com so you should have the id of the bot.

Comment: I do have the id of the bot i want to communicate to. But the whole reason i am doing this is because the app that is going to talk to my bot is not a bot.. but another c# app. Isnt that possible? @Ezequiel

Comment: So you have an app, that needs to talk with your bot? So basically, you are creating a custom "channel", right? Have you considered using DirectLine?

Comment: @EzequielJadib yes i want to create a custom channel. I haven't found info on how to do that through directline

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your comments you are trying to create a custom "channel/client" to talk with the bot.

For doing that, I would recommend taking a look to Direct Line which seems the way to go for achieving your requirement.

I'm not sure which language are you using, so I will send you pointers to both C# and Node.

These are samples that will show you how to create custom client using Direct Line to interact with your bot:

#### `C#`

- [Basic Direct Line sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLine)
- [Direct Line sample using Web Sockets](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-DirectLineWebSockets)

#### `Node.js`

- [Basic Direct Line sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine)
- [Direct Line sample using Web Sockets](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLineWebSockets)

All the samples are using a console app as the "custom channel".

Comment: The links mentioned above are inactive and returns 404.

Comment: Look for them @ https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples

Answer (score 4):

Since you're going to make an app talk to your bot and most likely be using [DirectLine](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/) after you and Ezequiel chatted, I created a series of screencaps on connecting to the DirectLine endpoint through Potsman. I'm going to assume that you know how to use environmental and global variables in Postman, [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments) are Postman's documentation for other people's benefit. Also, the DirectLine v3.0 docs are [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/).

Below is a capture of the directline endpoint you would request a token from, `{{DLsecret}}`'s guts looks like this, `Bearer <your-dl-secret>`: 
 [image: Call #1 Headers]

Here is an example of the response body you would receive on a valid call:
[image: Call #1 Response Body]

You may have noticed that I have some test results, in the screenshow below it has five (*vs four*) tests because I added the test verifying that the `conversationId` was set in the environment variables:
[image: Call #1 Tests and Results]

Here's the second query sent, which contains an actual message: 
[image: Call #2 Headers]

This is the request body which has the message:
[image: Call #2 Request Body (The message)]

And here is the response body:
[image: Call #3 Response Body]